# How to restore .C file association with notepad?

Tags: windows-8, file-association, notepad

I have to upload .C file for a contest! But once i have opened .c file with notepad and saved..After that notepad is the default opener of C files in my desktop. The problem is if i upload that file, the website cant recognize the kind of file as C file and producing illegal format error. How to restore this C file association with notepad and make it ask everytime "how to open"? I'm using windows 8. Thanks !!!

Comment: Just google file association: windows 8...

Comment: i cant find.. tats y askd here!! please help me with this

Comment: Right click your file -> Properties -> Opens with.

Comment: Unless you are saving using a different encoding then everyone else, notepad, shouldn't be modifying the file in such a way somebody else can't open it. Sounds like you are doing something wrong. Your question is not the actual question you should be asking, since solving it, won't result in a file somebody else can open ( considering they are unable to open the file on their hardware ).

Comment: File association on your computer shouldn't have anything to do with online submitting(unless you saved file in notepad with wrong encoding). I belive you have some other problem than that.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set Associations. It lists all the extensions and their associated programs. It lets you change the entries, but there doesn't seem to be a way to delete an entry.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the file -> Open With... -> (expand with "more options if needed) click a program you'd like to use, or if it's not on the list, scroll down to the bottom and press "Find an app on this PC" and then browse for the app you want to use.

By default, "Use this app for all .c files" is ticked, meaning that app will keep opening .c files(I suppose you left that ticked when you opened it with notepad).